# Does loading SVG as an external file make a noticeable difference in page loading speed?

Tags: html, css, performance, svg

I have a bunch of SVGs which sizes are around 25kb to 90kb each. Every page will have 3-5 and some of them will be repeatedly appear in different pages.

If I use an external file, that means all SVGs will be downloaded at once regardless if it will be used or not?

Does loading SVG as an external file make any noticeable difference in terms of page loading speed?

Comment: Does it make a difference? Possibly. Should you spend time on it? Probably not. I would skip all of the outdated "reduce requests" articles on the web and focus on making sure your site runs HTTP2. Beyond that it's really a question of code maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

My website is made from 80% SVG's although it is a bit slow it's ok

[My website](https://thearsham.com)

In general, if you use SVG's it is much more optimized you can see this website which shows you they are one of the best ways to use images in your website [resource](https://medium.com/larsenwork-andreas-larsen/optimising-svgs-for-web-use-part-1-67e8f2d4035) but in cases if you use a lot of SVG's it would become a bit slow

and also if you want to minify your SVG you can use this website [SVG minifier](https://www.svgminify.com/)